# Can you use Split Screen multiplayer in Modern Warfare 3 for LAN Party

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I plan on throwing a LAN party this week and we'll have a couple Xbox 360s there. I know that you and a guest can play on Xbox Live on the same machine, but I was wondering if we can have 4v4 over LAN with two Xbox 360s on the same network.

IIRC, this could not be done in World at War, and I didn't try with Black Ops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The competitive multiplayer split-screen support in MW3 is 2 players on the same screen, not 4.  You can play on Xbox Live or local via LAN, I believe.  I haven't tested the cooperative Spec-Ops mode, but I believe it supports 2 players on the same screen.

Modern Warfare 2 did not support split screen, but Black Ops had 2-player split screen support for multiplayer and Zombie mode.

Comment: does anyone know if Ps3 supports the same as well?

Comment: Can someone back up the cooperative Spec-Ops mode claim with evidence?